# mysql: make the server fail instead of just giving warnings

Tags: mysql, import, csv, warning

I have a `mysql 5.7` server.

I am trying to import some `.csv` files.

Sometimes it may so happen that these are malformed.

Here is a sample case:

```
  - 'mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.'
  stdout: |-
    Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: ' are not separated per hour."' for column 'story_points' at row 10
    Warning (Code 1262): Row 10 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
```

What I noticed is that the row was indeed somehow transformed and inserted (although in a bad way).

How can I prevent this behavior? I want the entire command to fail in such cases cause I cannot selectively roll back such malformed insertions.

Comment: [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html), TRADITIONAL mode. *Make MySQL behave like a “traditional” SQL database system. A simple description of this mode is “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column*. Or set this behavior separately by setting STRICT_ALL_TABLES.

Comment: Ι set the mode as follows: `| sql_mode      | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |` but still the file is imported;

Comment: @pkaramol what utility are you using to import these?